# Do powers that can be used as basic attacks trigger effects that happen when you make a basic attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, triggered-actions

If I have one of the Skald's at-will powers such as Bolstering Speech that triggers when I hit with a basic attack through Master of Stories and the half-elf 1/encounter at-will, can I trigger its effect off of a power that says it can be used as a basic attack?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour], it's a useful introduction to the site. I'm adding some more tags so people can find this question more easily.

Answer (score 12):

It depends on the **exact** writing of the power.

The Warlock's Eldritch Strike has "*This power counts as a basic attack.*" So all things that trigger on basic attacks do so.

However, powers such as the Paladin's Ardent Strike have "*This power may be used in place of a basic attack while charging*" and do not count as a basic attack, because it is only "in place of".